# Java find a group of words and categorise it from URL

Tags: java, url, search

I am trying to read information from URL and and writes the Country, Capital, Longitude and Latitude information in to a MySQL table.

> Country          Capital        Latitude     Longitude
>
> > Afghanistan        Kabul        34°28'N       69°11'E
> >
> > > Albania          Tirane  4      1°18'N      19°49'E

In URL like these and i want to find with the Keyword of Country, Capital, Longitude...  categories. How can i search inside the content? I tried below the code ,but the output is like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.1 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<!--   HTML coding exclusively with the CoffeeCup HTML 2010 Editor --> 
<!--          http://www.coffeecup.com                             --> 
<!--   Brewed on December 6 1994 1:09:21 PM                        --> 
<!--   Updated on September 6 2001 4:18:12 AM                      --> 
<!--   Updated on January 4 2011 8:22:45 PM                        --> 
<!--   Created by Dr. Gene Davis - Computer Support Group          --> 
<HEAD>
<title>Countries, Capitals, Latitude and Longitude Table</title>
    <META NAME="Title" CONTENT="CSGNetwork Countries, Capitals, Latitude META NAME="Title" CONTENT="CSGNetwork Countries, Capitals, Latitude and Longitude Table">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="For CSGNetwork.Com, Computer Support Group - Dr. Gene Davis">
```

and my code is here

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.csgnetwork.com/llinfotable.html");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)

            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
```

How can i directly search like in a text file from URL? Is it possible?

Comment: try jsoup (http://jsoup.org/) in order to parse html files.

Comment: If you think you can "read information from URL" rather than from the resource located by the URL, you are going to struggle with this task. You need to learn some Web basics.